# Did iOS 16 SceneKit change something about handling pixel format?

Tags: ios, scenekit, color-space, ios16

my app displays a video as texture on SceneKit's SCNNode.
Now I've just found that some videos looks different in iOS 16.4 from previous versions. The videos look more pale than they should be.
I looked up some documents and set `SCNDisableLinearSpaceRendering` as true in info.plist, they look exactly what they should be but then the problem is that the other videos which already looked fine now turned different.
But anyway it seems to relate to the linear or gamma color spaces regarding to [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710643).
What did they update? And is it possible to unify this behavior regardless of the video sources?

[image: What it should be]
[image: look pale]

---

**EDITED**

Here are some more information for videos.

sample video with no problem regardless of iOS version. https://storage.googleapis.com/test_video_jun/no_problem/master-playlist.m3u8

```
# no problem
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_tag_string=[27][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x001b
width=4096
height=1494
coded_width=4096
coded_height=1494
closed_captions=0
film_grain=0
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=2048:747
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=51
color_range=unknown
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
...
```

problematic video in iOS 16.4
https://storage.googleapis.com/test_video_jun/test_pale_problem/playlist-master.m3u8

```
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=Main
codec_type=video
codec_tag_string=HDMV
codec_tag=0x564d4448
width=3840
height=1920
coded_width=3840
coded_height=1920
closed_captions=0
film_grain=0
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=51
color_range=tv
color_space=bt470bg
color_transfer=reserved
color_primaries=reserved
...
```

---

**EDITED #2**

I can confirm it works well in iOS 16.1, but not in 16.2 and newer

Comment: Can you share one of the videos that show the issue?

Comment: Hi, here is a video! https://storage.googleapis.com/test_video_jun/test_pale_problem/playlist-master.m3u8

Comment: I edited the question with some more information for debug, but I got no idea where to start digging in :( Thanks

Comment: As you mentioned this seems to be a color management issue that appeared in iOS 16.4. I would file a bug report for Apple at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Comment: The second video uses the "bt470bg" color space. If that's possible you could try re-encoding the video with a different color space.

Comment: Thank you very much! So.. if I can't really change the video source, do you think if there's anything I can do from the iOS client side?

Comment: you can always try to use a fragment shader modifier (`SCNShaderModifierEntryPointFragment`) to perform some color processing, but it will be hard to make that work for any input video if they're not similar.

Comment: Thanks. Investigating each video input's color space and address it from the app sounds quite much :(

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed in iOS 17 beta 2 :)

Comment: Wow thank you for the update. I haven't got any response from Apple, did you manually check it?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it's fixed in iOS 17